# Can a bounty be awarded to a non-accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties, accepted-answer

I have a problem one of the users who asked awhile ago about something related to SQL injection. I provided an answer for his problem, and some solutions, but he did not accept my answer nor did he accept any other users' answers. Yesterday, someone opened a bounty on that question, to give my answer there some respect (it's really a good answer).

I want to know if I can be awarded that 500 pt. bounty even though the asker has not accepted my answer. [The relevant question and answer can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522941/sql-injection-vulnerable-code-even-we-are-sanitizing-the-input-mysql-real-escape/55523641#55523641)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) - _"As of June 2010, the bounty system is decoupled from accepting an answer"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, otherwise what's the reason of bounties? There are many questions with users, with their answer not accepted, get a bounty, for example (they're only for Python as I searched for Python):

*[What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949)*

*[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3/28154841#28154841)*

*[How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python/31599276#31599276)*

Of course, anyone can get the bounty.

Comment: It's really not that trivial. By default, bounty is awarded to the accepted answer.

Comment: @ShaWiz Not always tho